# How to refactor SwiftUI Image View to avoid Force Unwrap

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently using a ternary operator to first check if a `UIImage?` is not nil, and then use it in an `Image(uiImage: )`. Code for this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MealItemView: View {
    // PROPERTIES
    let thumbnail: UIImage?

    // BODY
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                ((thumbnail != nil) ?
                Image(uiImage: thumbnail!) :
                Image(systemName: "birthday.cake"))
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                
                Spacer()
            } //: HSTACK
        } //: ZSTACK
    }
}
```

It is an elegant way to display this, but the only problem with it is that it requires me to force unwrap the `uiImage` (!). I'm wondering if there is concise a way to refactor this so that I can avoid the force unwrap (because I got dinged points on an assignment for using force unwraps, and I'm looking for something better than "trust me bro it's fine").

I tried doing something like:

```swift
if let thumbnailImage = thumbnail {
    Image(uiImage: thumbnailImage)
} else { Image(systemName: "birthday.cake") }
```

but then it appears I would have to put all of the modifiers on each of the `Image` instances, which repeats code and is much less concise than the current implementation.

Comment: All the modifiers except for resizable can be put in a Group so they don’t need to be repeated.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this approach, a one liner with no forced unwraping, that works well:

```
 Image(uiImage: (thumbnail ?? UIImage(systemName: "birthday.cake")) ?? UIImage())
```